# How can I share my code with "Manage Library"?

Tags: google-apps-script

I just see the new "Manage Library" to share our code.
I get how to share a library and how to include a specific version in another script but I don't get how to call a function from the library.

In my library I have simply function

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("this is a test");
}
```

I open another spreadsheet and include the specific version of my library and I simply write

```
function onOpen() {
  test();
}
```

Sadly it doesn't run ...

Can you help me ?

**UPDATE**:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your "library project" you should save as a version (File > Manage versions)

2) In your "live project" you should add this library (Resources > Manage Libraries). Then add projectID  hash and important is Identifier. (e.g. **mylibrary**). This is class, how to call method in your code

> mylibrary.test();

Comment: Thank you. I simply miss the use of the identifier. Now it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the documentation for libraries and versions here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step screenshot explanation of how to both share and consume google apps script libraries.
http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/lib

Bruce